# Twitter API requests every 16 minutes

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, twitter, timeout

**Problem:**

I have written a piece of PHP code that checks whether a username in an array exist against the Twitter API protocol but I can't quite figure out how you can tell PHP or use jQuery together with PHP to check 180 usernames every 16 minutes (the limit with GET for Twitter API is 180 calls every 15 minutes).

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

**PHP code:**

```
foreach ($wordArray as $key => $value)
{
    echo '
        <p>
            English word: ' . $value['English'] . '<br>
            Latin word: ' . $value['Latin'] . '<br>
        </p>
    ';

    $username       = $value['Latin'];
    $url            = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json';
    $requestMethod  = 'GET';
    $getfield       = '?screen_name='.$username;

    $twitter        = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $result         = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                              ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                              ->performRequest();

    // Decode the JSON results
    $value          = json_decode($result);

    // Compare the resulting screen name with the input variable
    if (strtolower($value->screen_name) == $username)
    {
        echo '<p style="color:red;">The user exists!</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p style="color:green;">The user does not exist!</p>';
    }
}
```

**Desired solution:**

Say the $wordArray has 700 values, I would like to check 180 values each 16 minutes (to be on the safe side) and add them after each other. So 180 calls, print out result, wait 16 minutes, 180 calls, print out the results direct after, wait 16 minutes, etc.

Comment: `set_time_limit` and `sleep()` comes to mind, if blocking isn't an issue ?

Comment: I guess I need to put a counter somewhere, but do actually the first 180 calls get printed? When I tried sleep() with date('h:i:s'), I got both times first after the 10 seconds where elapsed.

Comment: Unless you are working with server push, there's no way of doing this with PHP. What you should do is to create a callback with javascript's  `setInteval` that will do a XHRequest (ajax) to you PHP script for retrieving data for you...

Comment: That sounds like an excellent idea, however I am not clear with how you divide the 700 value array and send 180 values between the intervals? Do you have an example for instance?

Comment: Or you can submit one every 5 seconds - just loop through your list and use `setInterval()` increasing the timer by 5000ms each time. `15mins * 60secs / 180reqs = 5`.

Comment: @doublesharp I agree, but I'm still not clear over how to keep track of the list if you have hundreds of values. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are doing it client side, just dump all the values out to an array and then loop through it making a call to the server using AJAX every 5 seconds. If you do it server side you could use a database or flat file (json maybe?) to store the status for each - not terribly efficient but it would work.

Comment: @doublesharp Worked nicely!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full working solution.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var attemp_count = 0;

            var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() 
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'twuserlookup.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {attemp_count: attemp_count++}
                }).done(function(data) 
                {
                    $('#mydiv').append(data);
                });
                if(attemp_count > 775) 
                {
                    clearInterval(auto_refresh);
                }
            }, 6000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**twuserlookup.php**

```
<?php
    // Initialize session
    session_start();

    // Check if array exist
    if (!isset($_SESSION['Words']))
    {
        // Include API protocol for Twitter and Simple HTML DOM
        require_once "dom/simple_html_dom.php";

        // Create DOM from URL or file
        $html = file_get_html('http://www.latinwordlist.com/latin-word-for/index.php');

        // Go through each word pair
        foreach(($html->find('body', 0)->find('li')) as $wordpair) 
        {
            // Find English words
            $items[]    = array (
                                'English' => strtolower($wordpair->find('a', 0)->innertext), 
                                'Latin' => preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', strtolower($wordpair->find('dd', 0)->innertext))
                            );
        }

        $wordArray = array_filter(array_slice($items, 0, 775, true));

        $_SESSION['Words'] = $wordArray;
    }

    // Include API protocol for Twitter and Simple HTML DOM
    require_once "TwitterAPIExchange.php";

    // Apply oAuth Access Token and Consumer Keys from Twitter Dev
    $settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token'        => "",
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
        'consumer_key'              => "",
        'consumer_secret'           => ""
    );

    if (array_key_exists('attemp_count', $_POST) && array_key_exists($_POST['attemp_count'], $_SESSION['Words'])) 
    {       
        echo '
            <p>
                English word: ' . $_SESSION['Words'][$_POST['attemp_count']]['English'] . '<br>
                Latin word: ' . $_SESSION['Words'][$_POST['attemp_count']]['Latin'] . '<br>
            </p>
        ';

        $username       = $_SESSION['Words'][$_POST['attemp_count']]['Latin'];
        $url            = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json';
        $requestMethod  = 'GET';
        $getfield       = '?screen_name='.$username;

        $twitter        = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        $result         = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                                  ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                                  ->performRequest();

        // Decode the JSON results
        $value          = json_decode($result);

        // Compare the resulting screen name with the input variable
        if (strtolower($value->screen_name) == $username)
        {
            echo '<p style="color:red;">The user exists!</p>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<p style="color:green;">The user does not exist!</p>';
        }

    }
?>
```